# createCriteria()

Tags: json, hibernate, grails, criteria

I'm trying to create a REST service which returns results in JSON format.

I've created a method which will return search results. It accepts a EnumMap of search parameters, and checks against these to build up the createCriteria.

**The issue I'm having is that the `validFor` which applies to the period a `tradingName` is valid for, gets returned regardless of whether the current date/time is in the "Valid for" period or not.**

In the example of JSON returned, it should only bring back the first of the `names`, as the other two `validFor` falls out of `start` and `end` range

**findCentre method**

```
def findCentre(EnumMap searchParams) {

    def c = Centre.createCriteria()
    def results = c.listDistinct {
        if(searchParams.containsKey(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.START_CENTRE_CODE_RANGE) && searchParams.containsKey(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.END_CENTRE_CODE_RANGE)) {
            between("code", searchParams.get(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.START_CENTRE_CODE_RANGE), searchParams.get(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.END_CENTRE_CODE_RANGE))
        }

        if(searchParams.containsKey(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.CENTRE_CODE_PARTIAL)) {
            like("code", "%" + searchParams.get(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.CENTRE_CODE_PARTIAL) + "%")
        }

        if(searchParams.containsKey(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.INDIVIDUAL_CENTRE_CODE)) {
            eq("code", searchParams.get(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.INDIVIDUAL_CENTRE_CODE))
        }

        if(searchParams.containsKey(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.CENTRE_NAME_PARTIAL)) {
            names {
                ilike("tradingName", "%" + searchParams.get(CENTRE_SEARCH_PARAMETERS.CENTRE_NAME_PARTIAL) + "%")
                validFor {
                    and {
                        le("start", new Date())
                        ge("end", new Date())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    results
}
```

The JSON response I get back looks like this

```
[
{
    "code": "1",
    "names": [
        {
            "trading_name": "ABC",
            "valid_time": {
                "start": "2013-02-13T08:54:31Z",
                "end": "2018-02-12T08:54:31Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "trading_name": "ABCDEF",
            "valid_time": {
                "start": "2013-03-31T23:00:00Z",
                "end": "2013-12-31T00:00:00Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "trading_name": "DEF",
            "valid_time": {
                "start": "2013-03-31T23:00:00Z",
                "end": "2013-12-31T00:00:00Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "email": "blah@blah.com"
}
]
```

I think the issue is in the `findCentre` method, but my current lack of Grails experience is causing me setbacks. Any help you can give me will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you get back are the complete `Centre` objects - you're restricting your search to those whose *current* name matches the pattern, but then returning all the names that matching objects have been known by regardless of date.

The easiest approach is likely to be to post-filter the criteria results rather than just returning them directly

```
Date now = new Date()
return results.collect { res ->
  [code: res.code,
   names: res.names.findAll { it.start <= now && it.end >= now }*.tradingName,
   email: res.email ]
}
```

which should give you JSON like

```
[
  {"code":"1",
   "names":["ABC"],
   "email": "blah@blah.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. That worked great. I understand it is returning the whole `Centre` object, but I would've thought the `validFor { and { le("start", new Date()) ge("end", new Date()) } }` part of the createCriteria() would've filtered the correct results. Please could you explain this a bit more? Sorry, completely new to Grails.

Comment: @GarethLewis The conditions in a criteria query are just a way of restricting which objects are chosen from the database, but each selected object is returned in full - in SQL terms they're the WHERE clause but don't affect what is SELECTed. You can use a `projections` block to define the SELECT but I couldn't come up with a way to do what you need with projections, which is why I suggested the post-filtering.

Comment: thanks again. I get what you are saying. Will look into `projections` just for info.